# How to configure nginx correct for both laravel and yii project?

Tags: nginx, yii

Im trying to configure nginx to serve laravel and yii project on same domain. My laravel project is working fine. Yii project also working but **assets** folder on yii project is giving **err_aborted** **not found 404**. All js css ... files are not found

```
server {

server_name mydomain.com;
index index.html index.php;
charset utf-8;
set $base_root /var/www;
# App 1 (main app)
location / {
    root $base_root/telemele/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/telemele.notice.log notice;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/telemele.error.log error;

    location ~* ^/index\.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/telemele/public/index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }
}

# App 2
location ~* /mahabat {
    alias $base_root/html/backend/web;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /mahabat/index.php?$query_string;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/mahabat.notice.log notice;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mahabat.error.log error;

    location ~* ^/mahabat/index\.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/backend/web/index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }
location ~* \.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif|\.swf|\.svg|\.tiff|\.pdf$ {
 try_files $uri =404;
 }

location ~ ^/assets/.+\.php(/|$) {
        deny all;
    }
}

# Files
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

# Error
access_log off;
rewrite_log on;

# Disable .htaccess access
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

What am i doing wrong? How to make nginx not to abort assets folder files? why it is giving not found?

Answer (score 4):

There might be a missing .htacces file at the frontend/web directory. If you have the same problem, I recommend you to use [this](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-shop/blob/master/frontend/web/.htaccess)

Comment: its not on apache, its on nginx sis